# Calculate a running total with a condition in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Sorry bad topic…
I need to calculate a running total but need to reset the total on a condition (when expected reached = 0).
I have this table:

```
Date, Registrations, Expected Registrations, Expected reached
        2020-03-01, 5, 4,1
        2020-03-02, 7, 5,1
        2020-03-03, 8, 6,1
        2020-03-04, 2, 5,0
        2020-03-05, 5, 4,1
        2020-03-06, 7, 5,1
        2020-03-07, 8, 6,1
        2020-03-08, 2, 5,0
```

Expected result with running total - the condition is that while “Expected Reached” <> 0 running total should be calculated. If “Expected Reached” = 0 the running total should start over from 0:

```
Date, Registrations, Expected Registrations, Expected Reached, Running Total
            2020-03-01, 5, 4,1, 1
            2020-03-02, 7, 5,1, 2
            2020-03-03, 8, 6,1, 3
            2020-03-04, 2, 5,0, 0
            2020-03-05, 5, 4,1, 1
            2020-03-06, 7, 5,1, 2
            2020-03-07, 8, 6,1, 3 
            2020-03-08, 2, 5,0, 0
```

I don't know how to partition my window function to do this. Maybe I have to create an intermediate calculation before but Im unsure. Any suggestions?

Edit:
edit2: removed my "on the fly question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(grp), 
  SUM(Expected_reached) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY `date`) Running_Total
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(Expected_reached = 0) OVER(ORDER BY `date`) grp 
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

Comment: If I add two fields to my table - product group and product, I add these in the OVER clause of the countif like this: countif(expected_reached=0) OVER (PARTITION BY product_group, product ORDER BY date_date asc,product_group,product). The problem is that grp will start over from 0 and then I dont have unique "islands" of data to do a partition over in the next step. Any suggestions?

Comment: it is not welcome on SO when you change "on-fly" question especially if it has already answer(s) - by changing the question - you invalidate the answer. Please post your new question(s) in a new post and we will be happy to help you

Comment: I thought why create a new post? But, ok I'll create it.

Comment: sure, that's the common "mistake" users do. but as I mentioned above it is not how SO works. SO is the question/answer site. Not discussion site. So one question at a time. Next question - new post and so on ... see you in next posts :o)

Answer (score 0):

Use a cumulative sum to define "islands".  Then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when expected_reached > 0
             then row_number() over (partition by grp, (expected_reached = 0) 
                                     order by date
                                    )
             else 0
        end) as running_total
from (select t.*,
             countif(expected_reached = 0) over (order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried this but did something wrong. Couldnt get this to work. My tables are a lot more complicated but I get the concept.